# Workaround to get leaflet canvas layer to display on top?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to show a leaflet canvas layer on top of a [L.geoJson](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) layer.  However, there seems to be a bug in leaflet where this cannot be done using the `bringToBack()`/`bringToFront()` methods.

```
var canvasTiles = L.tileLayer.canvas();
```

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/974

I've tried calling the following function at the end of the `drawTile()` method, in an attempt to get the canvas layer on top, but it doesn't work.

```
var interiorMaskLayer = null;
var exteriorMaskLayer = null;

function addMaskToBack(){
    insertAtTheBottom = true;
    if (interiorMaskLayer && exteriorMaskLayer){        

        map.removeLayer(interiorMaskLayer);
        map.removeLayer(exteriorMaskLayer);
        }   
    interiorMaskLayer = L.geoJson(interiorMaskGeojsonPoly, {style: interiorStyle})
    map.addLayer(interiorMaskLayer, insertAtTheBottom);
    exteriorMaskLayer = L.geoJson(exteriorMaskGeojsonPoly, {style: exteriorStyle});
    map.addLayer(exteriorMaskLayer, insertAtTheBottom);
}
```

Is there a workaround that can get the canvas layer to show on the top?

*using Leaflet-Leaflet-v0.5.1-0-gc1d410f.zip*

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that they are in different `DIV` elements, which have different z-indices, so no matter what z-index you give the child nodes, it's not going to appear in front of or in back of anything but its siblings.

Here's what I did, as a poor, but workable, solution:

Make the following changes to the leaflet source code (following the [leaflet-src.js](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v0.5.1/dist/leaflet-src.js) version 5.1 file), move the overlay pane to the tile pane:

[line 1782](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v0.5.1/dist/leaflet-src.js#L1782): `panes.overlayPane = this._createPane('leaflet-overlay-pane', this.tilePane);`

Remove only the tiles from the tile pane:

[line 8242](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v0.5.1/dist/leaflet-src.js#L8242):

```
_clearTileBg: function () {
        if (!this._animatingZoom && !this.touchZoom._zooming) {
            /* this._tileBg.innerHTML = ''; */
            var the_tiles = this._tileBg.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-layer');
            var the_count = the_tiles.length;
            while(the_count>0){
                var child = the_tiles[the_count-1];
                child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
                the_count--;
            }
        }
    }
```

And move the overlay pane when the tiles are moved (on zoom):

and add this line before [line 8230](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v0.5.1/dist/leaflet-src.js#L8230): `this._tilePane.appendChild(this.getPanes().overlayPane);`

These changes add the canvas to the tile pane, so that they are siblings, so that their z-indices will affect their position in relation to each other.  So, instead of clearing the tile pane (`this._tileBg.innerHTML = '';`), you need to remove the tile layers.  Also, leaflet alternates which pane is the tile pane so that it can do the zoom animation, so you need to move the overlay pane to the tile pane.

This fix is a work in progress.

Hope this helps!